# How can I minimize the console window in Eclipse without minimizing the other Eclipse windows?

Tags: eclipse

I have placed the console window in Eclipse in a separate window:

[image]

How can I the console window in Eclipse without minimizing the other Eclipse windows?

If I click on:

[image]

I get

[image]

which isn't what I want.

Comment: What does what you want look like? Is there a reason you're not using the OS's minimize window ability?

Comment: @nitind  the OS's minimize window ability is greyed out in the console window.